# Unresolved dependency when using H2 in Spring Boot CLI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, command-line-interface, h2

I'm trying to implement a small REST service that is using a h2 database using Spring Boot CLI (1.5.7).
But resolving the dependencies does not work. I'm getting the error:
"Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException" ... 
"Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE"

```
@Grab("h2")

import java.sql.ResultSet

class ContactRepository {
  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate jdbc

  List<Contact> findAll() { ... }
}
```

I thought by using @Grab("h2") Spring Boot would add the classes/jars to the class path. I was not able to find much sources about Spring Boot CLI (not the cloud version). 
I would be very grateful for some help.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

in your pom for the module and spring boot will detect the hsqldb on the classpath automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe your class has to be marked as a Spring managed class, i.e. add `@Repository` or `@Component` (doesn't matter) to your `ContactRepository` class.